# how to communicate an exit code from the QEMU guest to the host on arm64 / aarch64 (equivalent to isa-debug-exit)

Tags: qemu, arm64

I've found I can have the guest write to the port specified by the command line flag `isa-debug-exit`, and the value written to the port gets used as the exit code of QEMU (after some predictable transformation).
Is there an equivalent mechanism for aarch64 / arm64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the semihosting API for that: see 
[qemu-system-aarch64 exit from within the guest system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51282334/qemu-system-aarch64-exit-from-within-the-guest-system) for details (and also the caveats about needing to trust the code in your guest if you use it).

Comment: Looks like there's an open bug about supporting the `SYS_EXIT_EXTENDED` operation, which from the docs looks like the one I want. So I'm not sure QEMU supports this just yet?
https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1216845

Comment: That only applies for 32-bit. You said you were interested in 64-bit; for 64-bit the SYS_EXIT operation supports returning an exit status.